# Normalize Dataset in Python

Tags: python, normalize

So I have a dataset that I want to be normalized. The datset contains of bunch of numbers so im just going to post one line of it:

```
    1,1,22,22,22,19,18,14,49.895756,17.775994,5.27092,0.771761,0.018632,0.006864,0.003923,0.003923,0.486903,0.100025,1,0
```

Does anyone know how to do it? I'm not allowed to use Scikit-Learn.

Comment: provide your real data so we can know if you want to normalize by row or column

Answer (score 1):

Normalization takes all your values and transforms them so that they lie in between 0 and 1.

To perform this:

1. First find the minimum value (call it a) and the maximum value (call it b)
2. Take every value in your data set (call it d) and find (d-a)/(b-a).

(d-a) makes sure that the range goes from [a,b] to [0,b-a] and then dividing by (b-a) makes the range [0,1].

In Python you would first convert your dataset to a numpy array (a much more efficient data structure)

```
import numpy as np
d = np.array(your_dataset)
```

Then find the max and min

```
a = d.min()
b = d.max()
```

Finally you perform the operation

```
d = (d-a)/(b-a)
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Maybe I was not clear in my question, but this will only normalize one line right? My real dataset contains over 1000 lines of numbers.

Comment: No problem! When an operation is made on a numpy array it is broadcasted to every element in the array; so in this code all lines of numbers will be affected. Do you only want one line to be affected or the whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

In order to normalize a dataset you simply calculate the average `df['column_name'].mean()` and standard deviation `df['column_name'].std()` for the dataset and subsequently subtract the average from every value in your dataset and divide the result by the standard deviation.

So the result would look something like this:

```py
avg = df['column_name'].mean()
std = df['column_name'].std()
normalized = (df['column_name'] - avg) / std
```